# Spark 2.4.4 Avro Pyspark Shell Configuration

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, avro

I think I'm following proper [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#deploying%29.) to get pyspark to write avro files. I'm running Spark 2.4.4 I'm using Jupyter lab to run pyspark shell.

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.4 pyspark-shell'
spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("app")\
.set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.4')\
.set('spark.driver.memory', '3g')\
sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
...
```

`df.write.format("avro").save('file.avro')`

But I'm getting the following error. I'm not concerned about backward compatibility with Avro. Any ideas?

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.jdbc.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat could not be instantiated
```

Comment: Related jira issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27623. A workaround for now seems to be to use avro_2.11, you can test if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shaido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7579547/shaido) had the right idea. Using Version Spark-Avro 2.11 works.

```
import os    
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.3 pyspark-shell'    
spark_conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("app")\
    .set('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.3')
sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```